# How to stop a continuing PING in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that shuts down a list of servers which runs fine, but a part of the code is supposed to continually PING until the the server reports shutdown.

```
foreach ($line in Get-Content $GetLocation) {
    if($line -match $regex){
        echo "Server Name = $line "
#        Stop-Computer -ComputerName $Line -Confirm
         ping $line -t
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the script to stop when the **PING** returns a non-response of "Request Timed Out".  Is the switch **T** the right switch to use?  Any advice on this?

Comment: `ping -t` pings indefinitely until explicitly stopped.

Comment: I highly recommend you to use the native cmdlet [`Test-Connection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection) instead of the external `Ping` command for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want a continuous ping, you want to continuously ping it until it fails.

```
foreach ($line in Get-Content $GetLocation) {
    if($line -match $regex){
        echo "Server Name = $line "
#        Stop-Computer -ComputerName $Line -Confirm
         while((Test-Connection $line -Count 1 -Quiet) -eq $true){}
    }
}
```

You may want to put a sleep in there as well.

```
foreach ($line in Get-Content $GetLocation) {
    if($line -match $regex){
        echo "Server Name = $line "
#       Stop-Computer -ComputerName $Line -Confirm
        while((Test-Connection $line -Count 1 -Quiet) -eq $true){
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd also insert a counter so that you can time-out the loop. Else it could run forever waiting.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I guess I spent so much time working on this that I got a little tunnel visioned on the best way to write this out.